# R Shiny sliderTextInput "freezes" in the sense that every time it filters, I have to re-click to drag it to the next value

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having an issue with a Shiny slider that is driving me mad. In particular, when sliding the date slider in the app, when it filters based on the next date, I should be able to continue to hold my mouse clicker down and keep sliding to the next date. However, the slider is behaving such that once it selects another date, I have to re-click if I wish to go to the next date.

I believe that below is the minimum reproducible example. In particular, the data contains three rounds of dates from "2023-04-07" ranging "2023-06-30". If you drop this down to two rounds of such dates, and use the following as your data:

```
  c1<-as.Date(c("2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30",
                "2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30"))
  
  c2<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
  
  c3<-c(0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4,
        0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4)
  
  data<-data.frame(Date=c1,Label=c2,Number=c3)
```

If you used this shortened data, the slider works as expected. In the case that I have in the app (with three rounds of dates), the slider will behave correctly if you remove the row grouping from the data table. However, in my actual app I have removed the row grouping and it still does not work. I was, however, unable to reproduce that behavior with this abstracted data.

I'm hoping that someone can shed some light on why the slider is behaving in this way, which will hopefully allow me to solve the issue in my real app.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #Front end interface
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Analysis"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "slider",
        label = "Date",
        selected = "",
        choices = "" ,
        grid=TRUE)
      
      
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput('table'),
      plotOutput('trends')
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  c1<-as.Date(c("2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30",
                "2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30",
                "2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30"))
  
  c2<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
        "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
  
  c3<-c(0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4,
        0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4,
        0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4)
  
  data<-data.frame(Date=c1,Label=c2,Number=c3)
  

 
  
  
  filtered_data <- reactive(
    data[data$Date == input$slider,]
  )
  

  
  
  # Update sliderTextInput with choices and selected value
  updateSliderTextInput(
    session=session,
    inputId="slider",
    choices=unique(data$Date),
    selected=max(data$Date)
  )
  
 
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    
    #Create table object for renderDT
    
    datatable(filtered_data()
              ,
              extensions=c('Buttons','ColReorder','RowGroup'),
              options= list(
                dom= 'Btlp',
                columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(2,3), searchable = FALSE)),
                buttons = c('excel'),
                colReorder=NULL,
                rowGroup=list(dataSrc = 2)
                ),
                selection = 'single', #Options are multiple, single, or none
              filter = 'top')%>%
      formatStyle(
        'Number',
        backgroundColor=styleInterval(c(1.99,2.99,3.99), c('green', 'yellow', 'orange','red'))
      )
    
    })
  
  }  #Server close bracket



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I should be able slide the slider through the range of dates without re-clicking. However, the results varied from that, as described above.

Comment: It's impossible to determine what the issue is without a reprex that illustrates the problem. The code that you've provided works on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty quirky issue, but the problem seems to be due to the datatable object changing size on the page when it re-renders in the RStudio pane. I noticed the problem only appeared after the table seemed to "refresh" on the page so putting it into a slow-mo gif maker I saw that the two columns seem to actually change relative sizes when the table is refreshing. This causes the mouse cursor to become slightly unaligned from the slider dragger and appears to break the connectivity, requiring a re-click to establish click-and-drag functionality again. Here's a gif (grainy because compressed to be <2MB for SO) showing this behavior (with delay frames added as the datatable refreshes to be actually visible at normal speed):

[image: GIF of slider breaking when table refreshes]

There's not an obvious fix for this. Specifying the width of the two columns manually using `width="400px"` still seems to cause the problem because RStudio doesn't respect those widths absolutely, and specifying the column widths using `width = 4` and `width=8` respectively still allows it to change. Fortunately, this doesn't appear to be a problem in normal web browsers. When I launch the app in both Chrome and Edge the table renders as the same width no matter what and the slider functions perfectly.

Comment: This also may explain why the problem only shows up with larger datasets - the longer the time the datatable takes to refresh, the more likely it is that a mouse location check will fall in the time when it's misaligned.

Comment: You're right, it is an issue with the size of the table. When everything fits on one page, it works just fine. If I drag my app into a smaller screen where it you have to scroll to see the entire app, the quirky behavior of the app appears.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be related to `updateSliderTextInput` quirks.  You can try using `sliderTextInput` in a renderUI to get around that.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #Front end interface
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Analysis"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      uiOutput("myslider")
      
      # sliderTextInput(
      #   inputId = "slider",
      #   label = "Date",
      #   selected = "",
      #   choices = "" ,
      #   grid=TRUE)
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput('table'),
      plotOutput('trends')
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  c1<-as.Date(c("2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30",
                "2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30",
                "2023-04-07","2023-04-14","2023-04-21",
                "2023-04-28","2023-05-05","2023-05-12",
                "2023-05-19","2023-05-26","2023-06-02",
                "2023-06-09","2023-06-16", "2023-06-23","2023-06-30"))
  
  c2<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
        "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
  
  c3<-c(0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4,
        0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4,
        0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3,4,5,3,4,3.5,4.2,3.4,4)
  
  data<-data.frame(Date=c1,Label=c2,Number=c3)
  
  output$myslider <- renderUI({
    sliderTextInput(
      inputId = "slider",
      label = "Date",
      selected = max(as.Date(data$Date)),
      choices = unique(data$Date) ,
      grid=TRUE)
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive(
    data[data$Date == req(input$slider),]
  )
  
  #### Update sliderTextInput with choices and selected value
  # updateSliderTextInput(
  #   session=session,
  #   inputId="slider",
  #   choices=unique(data$Date),
  #   selected=max(data$Date)
  # )
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    
    #Create table object for renderDT
    
    datatable(filtered_data()
              ,
              extensions=c('Buttons','ColReorder','RowGroup'),
              options= list(
                dom= 'Btlp',
                columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(2,3), searchable = FALSE)),
                buttons = c('excel'),
                colReorder=NULL,
                rowGroup=list(dataSrc = 2)
              ),
              selection = 'single', #Options are multiple, single, or none
              filter = 'top')%>%
      formatStyle(
        'Number',
        backgroundColor=styleInterval(c(1.99,2.99,3.99), c('green', 'yellow', 'orange','red'))
      )
    
  })
  
}  #Server close bracket

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```